# Why is Burn elevating?

Tags: wix, burn

Why is my `perUser` bundle elevating?

I have 3 packages in my chain. Here's a log snippet:

```
[0BD8:0324][2016-10-06T15:23:57]i201: Planned package: NetFx461Web, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0BD8:0324][2016-10-06T15:23:57]i201: Planned package: ClientMSI, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0BD8:0324][2016-10-06T15:23:57]i201: Planned package: Dummy, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: None, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0BD8:0324][2016-10-06T15:23:57]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0BD8:0324][2016-10-06T15:23:57]i300: Apply begin
[0BD8:0324][2016-10-06T15:23:57]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[0BD8:0324][2016-10-06T15:24:03]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[0BD8:0324][2016-10-06T15:24:04]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[00B4:0B98][2016-10-06T15:24:04]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
```

As you can see in the log, just the ClientMSI package should be installed. It's a `dual purpose package`:

```
<Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="2" />
<Property Id="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Value="1" />
```

The user can select in my custom Burn UI (WPF) If he wants the msi installation to be `perUser` or `perMachine`. According to the selection of the user, I do this:

```
<MsiProperty Name='MSIINSTALLPERUSER' Value='1' />  <!--perUser-->
<MsiProperty Name='MSIINSTALLPERUSER' Value='' />   <!--perMachine-->
```

The bundle always gets installed `perUser` (I forced this by adding a dummy msi package in which I have set `InstallScope="perUser"`. This makes the bundle   `perUser` at compile time.

If the user selects `perUser` installation, there is one package which gets installed (ClientMSI) which is `perUser`, and the bundle also gets installed `perUser`.  There is no reason for elevation!

My guess is that burn assumes, ClientMSI is an `perMachine` package, because `ALLUSERS` is set to `2` and this confuses burn. Can somebody confirm that?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be getting a warning like this while compiling the bundle:

> Bundles require a package to be either per-machine or per-user. The MSI '{0}' ALLUSERS Property is set to '2' which may change from per-user to per-machine at install time. The Bundle will assume the package is per-{1} and will not work correctly if that changes. If possible, remove the Property with Id='ALLUSERS' and use Package/@InstallScope attribute instead.

WiX currently decides the scope of the MSI at compile time, so WiX probably decided that it would be per-machine.

Comment: Ok, so there's currently no chance to get burn work with a dual purpose package. :( ... However thank you very much for the confirmation!